# how do they put links to photoshop documents (html)

Tags: html

Do you know of any tutorial that can help a beginner like me do just like that.
I have really no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a link to a PhotoShop document is no different from [putting a link to anywhere else](http://w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="path_of_your_document">Get me</a>
```